# How to read data from excel and transfer it to a table using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an excel file where the data is mix of structured and unstructured, which has to be read and inserted into a table. The date is to be read from a text box at the top of sheet (as in image attached) and other columns have to be read from the excel columns. Also the date read from the text box is to be inserted into a new column with the existing columns. Please help on how we can achieve this through python. Or is there a better alternative to do this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide code of what you've been trying so far - so we could see your efforts, and then help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do that in Python and by my opinion there is not a better way to do it except in Python environment.

```
import xlrd 

# Location of file!

loc = ("path of file") 

# To open a file:

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

# For row 0 and column 0 

sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
```

Or

Note: don't forget to install openpyxl first if you haven't got used  with Python you may miss it. So you need pip install openpyxl

```
import openpyxl 


# location of the file 

path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\theFile.xlsx"

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 

sheet_obj = wb_obj.active 

# column integer is 1, not 0. 


cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 1) 


print(cell_obj.value)
```

Comment: But if you give us your code so far, maybe we will be more specific. By far my code should do the work. Wish luck...

Comment: Is your question being answered?

Comment: Hi Bear, thanks for the answer, i've used pandas to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to perform two entirely different types of operations - Excel parsing and image reading. For Excel parsing you can use the most sophisticated data processing library in python 'Pandas' and for image reading use another well known library 'OpenCV'.

- Just parse the excel using pandas
- Extract all the images columns from the dataframe
- Feed the images to OpenCV and get the date
- Add the date details as a separate column to dataframe
- Process the dataframe as per your requirements

Comment: I think the image he is referring to is an example of the excel he wants to read, I don't think he actually has any images to load into a dataframe. But I second using pandas to do this, it's highly versatile.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply, there are no images in the excel, i just attached a sample image of my existing spreadsheet which needs to be read.  I just want to pull out the date form the text box on the top of the sheet. how to go about that?